# mule remove json elements from json array

Tags: mule

I had json input like below

```
"products": {
  "p0": {
    "productId": "110",
    "productName": "bag"
  },
  "p1": {
    "productId": "160",
    "productName": "shoe"
  },
  "p2": {
    "productId": "140",
    productName": "watch"     
  }  
}
```

From mule I want the output like the one below

```
[
     {
       "productId": "110",
       "productName": "bag"
     },
     {
       "productId": "160",
       "productName": "shoe"
     },
     {
       "productId": "140",
       "productName": "watch"
     }
]
```

Because I need to pass the above output format to other inbound.
Anyone help how to convert my input json into above output json.

Thanks in advance for all

Comment: Can you use DataMapper? (Mule Enterprise only)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want using some MEL and json transformers:

```
  <json:json-to-object-transformer
                returnClass="java.util.HashMap"  />

  <set-payload value="#[($.value in payload.products.entrySet())]" />

  <json:object-to-json-transformer />
```

If you're going to have more complex transformation, I would write a custom transformer, or script transformer using Groovys JsonBuilder and JsonSlurper or potentially Datamapper.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mule 3.7 and above, you can do it simply and easily with the [dataweave](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-reference-documentation) component :-

```
 <flow name="Testlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/test" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
      <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
        %output application/json
         ---
        payload.products map (
           $  
         )
       ]]></dw:set-payload>
      </dw:transform-message>
</flow>
```